# Read more read less function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a read more read less function with html and js, function is working fine with one paragraph when I use again for another paragraph then second function not working, I would like to multiple use in same page, please check

```js
function myFunction() {
  var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
  var moreText = document.getElementById("more");
  var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");

  if (dots.style.display === "none") {
    dots.style.display = "inline";
    btnText.innerHTML = "READ MORE";
    moreText.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    dots.style.display = "none";
    btnText.innerHTML = "READ LESS";
    moreText.style.display = "inline";
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.<span id="dots">...</span><span id="more"> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</span></p>
<div class="col-md-12">
    <button onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn" class="rm">READ MORE</button>
</div>
```

Comment: are you wondering why it doesn't work initially?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. But if you plan to use multiple of these in the same page, you will need to customize the function to take an ID (since you're getting element by a hard-coded ID), or use a more clever means of determining which element is nearest the "Read More/Less" button(s). Having elements with duplicate IDs can produce very strange (incorrect) behavior, so don't do that.

Comment: How did you implemented this for multiple paragraph? Can you add the demonstration of that with issue?

Comment: You can write your logic based on the structure instead of `id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to find out various element with relation to button which was clicked. You can also use class name instead of Id to select elements.

```js
function myFunction(event) {
  const parentSibling = event.target.parentElement.previousElementSibling;
  const dots = parentSibling.querySelector(".dots");
  const moreElement = parentSibling.querySelector(".more");
  const btnElement = event.target;

  if (dots.style.display === "none") {
    dots.style.display = "inline";
    btnElement.innerHTML = "READ MORE";
    moreElement.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    dots.style.display = "none";
    btnElement.innerHTML = "READ LESS";
    moreElement.style.display = "inline";
  }
}
```

```html
<p>1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.<span class="dots">...</span><span class="more" style="display: none"> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</span></p>
<div class="col-md-12">
    <button onclick="myFunction(event)" class="myBtn" class="rm">READ MORE</button>
</div>

<p>2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.<span class="dots">...</span><span class="more" style="display: none"> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</span></p>
<div class="col-md-12">
    <button onclick="myFunction(event)" class="myBtn" class="rm">READ MORE</button>
</div>
```

You can also use a single handler in the parent, which will execute the logic based on the clicked element `myBtn`.

```js
function myFunction(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if(!event.target.classList.contains('myBtn')) {
    return;
  }
  const parentSibling = event.target.parentElement.previousElementSibling;
  const dots = parentSibling.querySelector(".dots");
  const moreElement = parentSibling.querySelector(".more");
  const btnElement = event.target;

  if (dots.style.display === "none") {
    dots.style.display = "inline";
    btnElement.innerHTML = "READ MORE";
    moreElement.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    dots.style.display = "none";
    btnElement.innerHTML = "READ LESS";
    moreElement.style.display = "inline";
  }
}
```

```html
<div onclick="myFunction(event)">
  <p>1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.<span class="dots">...</span><span class="more" style="display: none"> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</span></p>
  <div class="col-md-12">
      <button class="myBtn" class="rm">READ MORE</button>
  </div>

  <p>2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.<span class="dots">...</span><span class="more" style="display: none"> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</span></p>
  <div class="col-md-12">
      <button class="myBtn" class="rm">READ MORE</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its working, Thank you so much your precious time much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without javascript all together, just by using a checkbox and the sibling selector (~).

```css
section .section-toggler,
section .more {
  display: none;
}

section .section-toggler:checked ~ p > .more {
  display: inline; 
}

section .section-toggler:checked ~ p > .dots {
  display: none;
}

section > label {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #71acbf;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <input class="section-toggler" id="section-1" type="checkbox" />
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    <span class="dots">...</span>
    <span class="more">Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</span>
  </p>

  <label for="section-1">Read more...</label>
</section>
```